# Prove that if A, B and C are countable sets, then A∪B∪C is a countable set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if A, B and C are countable sets, then A∪B∪C is a countable set.

> $$ A = {3,6,9,..}$$
>   $$ B = {4,7,10,..}$$
>   $$C = {5,8,11,..}$$

$f: N > A$
$F(n) = 3n$

$f: N > B$
$F(n) = 3n + 1$

$f: N > C$
$F(n) = 3n + 2$

> $$ A∪B∪C = {3,6,9,..} ∪ {4,7,10,..} ∪ {5,8,11,..}  = {3,4,5,6,7,8,9..}$$

$F(n) = n + 2$

This is my answer but I am not sure if that is correct!

Comment: Are you supposed to prove that where A, B, and C are any three countable sets, or in this particular example?

Comment: Any three countable sets

Comment: Ok then you shouldn't assume that A is {3,6,9...} for instance. A doesn't even have to be a set of numbers.

Comment: What should I do instead?

Comment: You know there exist surjections $f:N->A$, $g:N->B$, $h:N->C$. You don't know how they look like, though.Try to construct a surjection from $N$ to $A\cup B\cup C$ by interweaving $f$, $g$ and $h$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $A_1:=A$, $A_2:=B$ and $A_3=C$ are countable.

For $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, let's consider three injections

$$\psi_i:A_i\to \mathbb N.$$

For all element $e$ in $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$, let's define

$$m(e):=\min_{\substack{i\in\{1,2,3\} \\ e\in A_i}} i$$

and

$$\chi(e):=(m(e),\psi_{m(e)}).$$

Then $\chi:A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\to \{1,2,3\}\times\mathbb N$ is well defined because $m(e)\in\{1,2,3\}$ by definition, and it is an injection.

Therefore, $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are both finite, then so is A ∪ B, and any finite set is countable.
Suppose A is finite and B is countably infinite. Then there are sequences a1, a2,...,an
and b1, b2,... that contain every element of these sets, respectively. Thus,
a1, a2,...,an, b1, b2,... is an infinite sequence that contains every element of A ∪ B, so
A ∪ B is countable.

Similarly, if B is finite and A is countably infinite then A ∪ B is countable.
Finally, suppose that A and B are both countably infinite. Then there are infinite
sequences a1, a2,... and b1, b2,... that contain every element of these sets, respectively.
Thus, a1, b1, a2, b2,... is an infinite sequence that contains every element of A∪B, so A∪B
is countable.

Comment: hmm... your answer doesn't address the set $C$ at all isn't it?